# If condition strange behaviour

Tags: arduino, atmega, c

I brought an ATmega328P (SMD) and burned a Duemilanove Bootloader. Everything seemed to be working fine until I tested out conditional statements.

Average set of analog val are: 84 , 143 , 255

Here is the code:

```
int svalue(int analogVal){
    if((analogVal > 135) && (analogVal < 200)){
        return 1;
    }
    if((analogVal > 200) && (analogVal < 300)){  
        return 2;
    }
    if((analogVal > 50) && (analogVal < 100)){
        return 3;
    }   
}
// Here is my main loop
void loop() {
  int pval = svalue(analogRead(A1));
  mySerial.write(pval);
}
```

But the above code is always returning '1'. I have tried `Serial.print` to debug the value of analogVal. Even if the value is 255 it returns 1. Is it a bootloader problem?

Comment: Did you read the compiler warnings?

Comment: What is int defined in your system as?  You might try changing it to unsigned short.  If you print the value of analogVal just before the "return 1" statement , what do you see?

Comment: @tcrosley well but if it's an uint_8 it might also return two or three, if it's an int_8 it might return also three... I never use "int" when programming on a micro but I'm not sure on how the problem can lie there this time. That code have many other problems too anyway.

Comment: @tcrosley or you are saying that for 84 it works the first time, so the return register is set to one and never touched again, and the thing silently fails? that would be awesome.

Comment: `int` on AVR is 16-bit by default, but can be forced to 8-bit with a compiler switch (**don't do this**).

Comment: @VladimirCravero I agree, I never use int either on an embedded system, too ambiguous.  I think the printout of the value before the return statement will be more useful (besides stepping through the code and looking at the registers, don't know if the OP can do that).

Comment: Hey Guys i have added the main loop also for more info. how do i fix this issue ? have also tried re-uploading the bootloader no luck.

Comment: @tcrosley if what Ignacio says is correct that's a true riddle. I read that code like 10 times and don't really understand why it's not working

Comment: @tcrosley before returning '1' it is giving me all the three values this is purely crazy i get '84', '144', '255' at times

Comment: @op you mean that you put the print just before the return 1 and get exactly the three expected values?

Comment: @VladimirCravero Let me explain the values are coming from a analog switch. and now when i print it before it returns '1' it shows 144 and when i press the next switch it freezes and displays nothing and when i press the 1st switch again it gives me 144 again in my monitor

Comment: ok I am lost. Let's just forget switches and such, that's embedded c and I'd care only of the values you are passing to the function. Add to the question the sequence of inputs you give to the function and the various returned values.

Comment: I don’t understand why it is not working. Add a “return 0;” at the end of the “svalue” function and test again.

Comment: @AmitHasan I can back that. **Always** have a return statement present in any branch of a function not returning void.

Answer (score 3):

Test the code in a structured, predictable way. Simplify it where possible. Print all values.

Post entire programs (where practical) so people can test it on their machines. Incomplete programs are hard to test, so it is harder to help.

First, what is `mySerial`? Is it an instance or reference to `Serial`? Replace `mySerial` with `Serial`. Then it is clear to everyone what is being used.

Secondly `Serial.write(val)` literally prints a binary byte, the lower 8 bits of of an int. which will be interpreted as an ASCII character by the Arduin's serial monitor. Binary values can be very awkward to debug.

Use `Serial.print(val)` or `Serial.println(val)` instead. This converts a binary number (e.g. in an int) to a 'human readable' number, by default printed as base 10, using the digits '0' to '9' (see the [Arduino Serial documentation](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial))

When testing and something strange is happening, remove every hard to control or predict part. 'Instrument' with print statements to see what is happening. (or get a debugger)

Change

```
int svalue(int analogVal){
    if((analogVal > 135) && (analogVal < 200)){
```

to

```
int svalue(int analogVal){
    Serial.print("entering svalue - analogVal=");
    Serial.println(analogVal);

    if((analogVal > 135) && (analogVal < 200)){
```

So we can see what is happening inside svalue.

To a reasonable approximation analogRead(A1) generates random numbers with an unknown range.

Replace it with either a fixed value, or something very predictable, like a `for` loop.

Change

```
void loop() {
  int pval = svalue(analogRead(A1));
  mySerial.write(pval);
}
```

To:

```
void loop() {
  int pval = analogRead(A1);     // = svalue(analogRead(A1));
  Serial.print("analogRead(A1)=");
  Serial.println(pval);
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<1024; i+=10) {    // print range of analogRead, in steps of 10
    pval = svalue(i);
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(" svalue(i)=");
    Serial.print(pval);    // mySerial.write(pval);
    Serial.println();
  }
}
```

Now you have something which can be debugged more easily.

Edit:
Changed the for loop to use steps of 10 to make it easier to see what is happening, and retained printing `analogRead(A1)` value. At least this approach tests `svalue()`.

It is plausible that the something is wrong with that analogue input, or the electronics connected to A1 is broken, and hence analogRead returns nonsense.

Try each different analogue input.
Try to use something simple and (mostly) predictable like two fixed resistors (say 1K and 1K) to make a voltage divider for the analogue input to measure. Or try something controllable like a potentiometer which should allow you to see the voltage being driven in a direction, and test most of the range.

If you have an effective way to test binary values, and do need the value from `svalue()` to be output as a binary character code, replace `Serial.print(pval);` with `Serial.write(pval);`.